# Windows 10 MSI Uninstall Fails with 1721

Tags: wix, windows-10, uninstallation

I have an Excel Add-in that uses a Wix (3.10) install script. The installation works fine. However, if the user tries to remove the add-in through **System | Apps & Features**, it fails with "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run." Looking at the uninstall log, I see this:

```
Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: _BDF865EC_34B3_4B29_986C_98D6EC1A9807, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI2FE4.tmp, command: /uninstall="C:\Users\Windows10\AppData\Local\myCompany\myProduct\myAddin.dll" /privileges=user
```

The action that it is balking at is this:

```
<CustomAction Id="_BDF865EC_34B3_4B29_986C_98D6EC1A9807" BinaryKey="adxregistrator_exe" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='/uninstall="[TARGETDIR]$(var.myProject.TargetFileName)" /privileges=user' Impersonate="yes" />
```

However, if I re-run my installer and select 'Remove', it uninstalls fine. Also, If I run the uninstall from a command line (using the msiexec command found in the registry entry for this product), it also uninstalls fine.

**Also:**

- This only happens in Windows 10. Older versions of Windows are fine.
- I have replicated on several machines, including a fresh install.
- I have an older installer (a VS2010 Setup Project), the problem happens with that installer as well.
- I have tried with UAC at different elevations, no difference.
- I have seen other posts here about changing the **Impersonate** setting to "no", no difference.

It seems to me that there is a problem with the new **Windows Apps & Features** app, but I have yet to find anything on the Microsoft forums.

**Update:**

A Wix user posted this: [DTF Bug with new Windows 10 Apps and Features](http://blog.iswix.com/2015/08/dtf-bug-with-new-windows-10-apps-and.html). Also, we have tried a variety of commands (thinking it was a UAC issue), none of them work, even 'built-in' Windows commands fail.

Comment: At first glance this should never work because TARGETDIR will not be preserved between install and uninstall unless you explicitly save and restore it. You'd be much safer using the [#file-key] as the target path to your executable on disk. Ideally you'd also decipher what the registrator does and just put those entries in (for example) the Registry table.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem when I am trying to uninstall our software with the Windows Apps & Features app. I am calling a custom action before the files are removed which relies on a installed file. The file in question is on the target system. Everything works as expected when I uninstall via Programs and Features.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue and finally came with this solution:
Win 10 Apps & Features uninstaller checks for the WindowsInstaller registry value and behaves correctly when this value is not present

1) Define the custom action

```
<CustomAction Id="DeleteWindowsInstallerValue" Return="ignore" Directory="TARGETDIR" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"
ExeCommand= "reg.exe DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode] /v WindowsInstaller /f" />
```

2) schedule the action in the InstallExecuteSequence

```
<Custom Action="DeleteWindowsInstallerValue" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
```

Honza

Comment: I tested this manually (ie, via regedit), and removal of the key didn't seem to work for me. However, I have discovered that Win10 Anniversary update does not have the issue. I think Microsoft may have fixed it on their end.